# PHP doesn't replace less than character

Tags: javascript, php, replace

I have a string:

```
if (z > data.angles[k] - 45 && z < data.speed_limit)
```

I am trying to replace < and spaces before/after:

```
$text = str_replace(' < ', '<', $text);
$text = str_replace(" < ", "<", $text);
```

But get this:

```
if (z > data.angles[k] - 45 && zdata.speed_limit)
```

So there is no less than at all. I dont understand what's wrong. Can you help?
P.S. It's JS code which I am trying to change.

Comment: Your code works https://3v4l.org/Sj3R5  Make sure you show us __correct code snippet__

Comment: Also if you view result in browser, be aware that `<` is a start of html-tag.

Comment: Also, "I am trying to replace < and spaces before/after… It's JS code which I am trying to change"—what are you actually trying to do here? There's a good chance this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Answer (score -1):

I've checked your code and it worked. Check code result in online sandbox http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3da3ba1db490683048089fd9b2317cd1f412121e

Maybe you are looking result in the browser and **<>** are used for creating html tags and that is why you don't see them. If so, try check your code result through Cntr+U in browser.